# How to transfer the item ID from the game [World of Warcraft 1.13.3] to my addon?

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I want to get the item ID by clicking on it with the mouse pointer with the modifier key or the item ID below the mouse pointer by clicking on the keyboard key.

Or how else can I get the ID of the selected item in my addon?

I found the documentation:

https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Using_bindings.xml_to_create_key_bindings_for_your_addon

https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_Frame_SetPropagateKeyboardInput

But I don’t understand how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways to do this, such as displaying the information in a tooltip when you mouseover, but here is a simple solution that basically does what you asked for: displaying the item and its id in the chat window when you shift-click.

This solution creates a listener who checks for the first time you open your bags.  It then attaches code to every slot in your open bag telling it to print the information when shift-clicked.  When this code is printed to slots in your final bag, it also tells the listener to stop functioning so as to avoid wasting CPU resources.

```
local listener = CreateFrame("Frame");
listener:SetScript("OnEvent", function()
    for bag=1, 5 do
        for slot=1, GetContainerNumSlots(bag-1) do
            local frame = _G["ContainerFrame" .. bag .. "Item" .. slot];
            if (frame and not frame.isHooked) then
                frame.isHooked = true;
                frame:HookScript("PreClick", function()
                    if (IsShiftKeyDown()) then
                        local itemLink, __, __, itemID = select(7, GetContainerItemInfo(bag - 1, frame:GetID()));
                        if (itemID) then
                            print(itemLink .. " " .. itemID);
                        end
                    end
                end);
                if(bag == 5) then
                    -- stops this from continuing to execute after all bags have been openned at least once.
                    listener:UnregisterEvent("BAG_UPDATE");
                end
            end
        end
    end
end);
listener:RegisterEvent("BAG_UPDATE");
```

References:

- [GetContainerNumSlots](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetContainerNumSlots)
- [GetContainerItemInfo](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetContainerItemInfo)
- [RegisterEvent](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_Frame_RegisterEvent)
- [UnregisterEvent](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_Frame_UnregisterEvent)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can’t check the code in the game yet. But is there a variant of your code if the item is not in the bag, but in the loot window?

Comment: The item is in the loot window and I click on it with the modifier key. How do I track this event?

Comment: If I can track this event, then how can I get where the item is: in a bag or in loot?

Comment: See [C_Loot events](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Events#C_Loot) and [GetLootSlotInfo(i)](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetLootSlotInfo) to research loot in the loot window instead of bags.

Comment: No, I need equal action in the bag window and in the loot window. For example: "press the mouse button with the modifier button on the keyboard" or "press the button on the keyboard and get the item that is under the mouse pointer at the moment". Is it possible to create?

Comment: There is some "_G [" LootFrameItem ".. slot];" for which you can use the hook "PreClick"?

Comment: "function()" (bind to "PreClick") does not work with the bags of the addon "Bagnon" (without this addon I did not check).